# What native mysql class should I port to from Zend_Db? ( No PDO or Mysqli )

Tags: php, mysql, zend-db

I'm dealing with a client who has a legacy cPanel account where the php installation was not compiled with `PDO` nor `Mysqli` therefore my Zend_Db code is useless since it relies on either of those.

What library/class should I go with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends what you're trying to achieve, it's possible to extend Zend Frameworks Zend_Db and add a mysql adapter. If this is too much trouble there are two library's that are probably worth looking at, the first depends on PEAR being installed and is [MDB2](http://pear.php.net/package/MDB2) the other is [ADOdb](http://adodb.sourceforge.net/) both offer OO DB abstraction and work with the mysql extension.

Answer (score 0):

Meh - I just made my own class mimicking the exact methods and functionality of Zend_Db so I don't have to reprogram a lot of the code.

Answer (score 0):

- [ezSQL](http://www.justinvincent.com/docs/ezsql/ez_sql_help.htm) (used by Wordpress)
- [Codeigniter database class](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/index.html)

Comment: Can I simply use the CodeIgniter DB Class separately from the whole framework?

Comment: I tried to use Kohana's but it was integrated with the whole framework.. so far only Zend's is the only "loosely coupled" DB Class though it doesn't support lowest common denominator mysql, surprisingly.